# pySpark check if dataframe exists

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, exists

Is there a way to check if a dataframe exists in pySpark?

I know in native python, to check if dataframe exists:

```
exists(df_name) && is.data.frame(get(df_name))
```

How can this be done in pySpark? Since command `exists` throws an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is same as Petel code. You can import the dataframe type.

```
 from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

 df= sc.parallelize([
 (1,2,3), (4,5,7)]).toDF(["a", "b", "c"])

 if df is not None and isinstance(df,DataFrame):
      #<some operation>
      print("dataframe exists")
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to know if `df_name` is defined and pointing to a `DataFrame`. None of the answers above handle the case where `df_name` is not set. This does:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

try:
  if df_name is not None and isinstance(df_name,DataFrame):
    print('df_name exists')

except NameError as error:
  print('df_name does not exist and not defined')
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:  `df_name is not None and isinstance(df_name, DataFrame)`

Comment: Got NameError: 'DataFrame' is not defined

Comment: import this library `from pyspark.sql import DataFrame`